# How to do indirect variable substitution in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to build another job listed in a propsfile using a for loop

The jobs to build are listed in propsfile

```
JOB_COUNT=3
JOB_1=JOB_ONE
JOB_2=JOB_Two
JOB_3=JOB_THREE
```

pipeline script

```
stage ('Trigger Job') {
    steps {
        load "propsfile"
        script {
            for (int i=1; i <= "${JOB_COUNT}".toInteger(); i++) {
                build "$JOB_$i"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so I receive this error

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: JOB_ for class: WorkflowScript
```

I want to know if its possible to do this in groovy just like in bash?

Or should I change the way I approach this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Pipeline Utility Steps plugin installed, you can read properties file as a map.
have a look at below snippet:

```
stage ('Trigger Job') {
    steps {
        script {
            def props = readProperties file: "propsfile"
            def count = props['JOB_COUNT'].toInteger()
            for (int i=1; i <= count; i++) {
                build props["JOB_$i"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach also works for me. But do you know if indirect variable calls are possible in groovy?

Comment: No, indirect variable calls are not possible in groovy.